# using .then inside if statement to parse JSON

Tags: javascript

I am making this api request, the check is performed inside the if statement, how do I make to include a then json() without doing another request?

```
  database = () => {
    const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    console.log('loading ...');
    var url = 'https://api.com./' + currentUser.email;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          console.log(response.status);
          console.log('denied');
        }
        else if (response.status === 200) {
          fetch(url)
            .then(promise => promise.json())
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data)
            })
        }
        else {
          console.log('?')
        }
      });
  }
```

I tried using `response.json()` but the thing is wrapped in a promise, couldn't access formated data.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.then is not a function

Please advise

Comment: Where is `response.json()` in your code?

Comment: Are you sure that error is correct? You're not using `response.then` anywhere.

Comment: why `fetch(url)` again in else if ? where is `response.then` in your code?

Comment: why do you have 2 fetch(url) - I believe it supposed to be only one fetch call for a response

Comment: Both response.json() and response.then() not present in your code make sure you pasted the right code & if you were using response.then then you are doing it in wrong way. You are already using then on fetch call which will give you the actual response returned by server not the promise instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using the `async` - `await`. Makes your code cleaner and shorter.

```
const database = async() => {
    console.log('loading ...');
    var url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';
    let response = await fetch(url)
        if (response.status === 404) {
          console.log(response.status);
          console.log('denied');
        } 
        else if (response.status === 200) {
          const data = await response.json()
          console.log(data)
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

A better option would be to `throw` errors instead of logging them, thus breaking the `then` chain:

```js
url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 404)
      throw new Error('not found');
    if (response.status !== 200)
      throw new Error('error');
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => console.log('ok', data))
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err.message));
```

You can also make a generic function for this and use it instead of just `fetch` all the time:

```
function fetchOrFail(url, opts) {
    return fetch(url, opts)
        .then(r => {
            if (r.status !== 200)
                throw new Error('fetch error ' + r.status);
            return r;
        })
}
```

Comment: It works I implemented a similar logic but I am trying to get rid of parse JSON error, the console.log(data) always get executed even on 404